# Json body is truncated using non english characters in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, urllib2

I am using an API gateway and AWS Lamdba function as Proxy to my company's API (C# Web API 2.0)
The Lambda function in written in Python 2.7 and I am using Pyhton's urllib2 to pass the http request to the API.

I encounterd a strange issue When I am sending a json body containing hebrew characters.
The Json is being cut in the middle. I am making sure that the Json sent from the Lambda is complete, but the json body received in the Lambda is being turcated somewhere along the way.

This is the Lambda function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib2
import HTMLParser


base = "http://xxxxxx/api"

hparser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Got event\n" + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Form URL
    url = base + event['queryStringParameters']['rmt']
    print('URL = %s' % url)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    if 'body' in event:
        if event['body']:
            print('BODY = %s' %  json.dumps(event['body'], ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8') )
            req.add_data(json.dumps(event['body'], ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8'))


    # Copy only some headers
    if 'headers' in event:
        if event['headers']:
            copy_headers = ('Accept', 'Content-Type', 'content-type')
            for h in copy_headers:
                if h in event['headers']:
                    print('header added = %s' % event['headers'][h])
                    req.add_header(h, event['headers'][h])


    # Build response
    out = {}
    headersjsonstr = ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '')
    response_header = {}

    try:
        print('Trying here...')
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        out['statusCode'] = resp.getcode()
        out['body'] = resp.read()
        for head in resp.info().headers:

            keyval = head.split(':')
            if any(keyval[0] in h  for h in headersjsonstr): 
                response_header[keyval[0]] = keyval[1].replace('\r','').replace('\n','').strip()

        print('response_header = %s' % response_header )
        out['headers'] = response_header
        print('status = %s' % out['statusCode'] )

    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:

        out['statusCode'] = e.getcode()
        out['body'] = e.read()
        out['headers'] = e.headers
        print('status = %s' % out['statusCode'] )

    return out
```

This is the Post request raw body Json

```
{"company":"שלום","guests":[{"fullname":"אבי","carno":"67"}],"fromdate":"2018-10-10","todate":"2018-10-10","fromtime":"07:31","totime":"07:31","comments":null,"Employee":{"UserId":"ink1445"}}
```

And this is what I am getting on the API:

```
"{\"company\":\"שלום\",\"guests\":[{\"fullname\":\"אבי\",\"carno\":\"67\"}],\"fromdate\":\"2018-10-10\",\"todate\":\"2018-10-10\",\"fromtime\":\"07:31\",\"totime\":\"07:31\",\"comments\":null,\"Employee\":{\"UserId\":\"ink1
```

Again, when I am sending only English letters everything is fine.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No. I ended up using node.js instead of Python in the Lambda and it is now working. Thanks

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue. I am not using any non-english chars but I am using Python 3.6 Lambda. Some but not all of my message bodes are truncated at about 500 chars. My Lambda reads from SQS which received messages from API Gateway.

Comment: Update to comment above: I just tested with node 8.10 and still see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely your json buffer is too small, and you are getting overflow truncation.

The size was probably set assuming ASCII or utf-8 encoding, and your unicode characters are wider (consume more bytes).

Depending on what json package you are using, you may be able to set an option for unicode or you might need to adjust the buffer size manually.